# Rails I18n errors parsing simple YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I'm just starting to use Rails I18n a with very basic task and I'm getting a confusing error message:

```
can not load translations from c:/Sites/usrochr/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (c:/Sites/usrochr/config/locales/en.yml): couldn't parse YAML at line 5 column 2>
```

My YAML file is [very basic] config/locales/en.yml [i don't see the syntax error]:

```
en:
  users:
    title: "this is english"
```

and the code calling it in the views/users/index.html.erb file is also simple :

```
    <hr><%= t "users.title" %><hr>
```

fyi -i am running ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.7. Not sure where i have gone astray.....

Comment: Are you sure you have no tabs in en.yml?

Comment: The error message indicates that the error ocurrs on line 5. Is there anything else in the file beside the three lines shown?

Comment: Thanks BroiSatse!!!!- removing the tabs in .yml did it- thanks!!!

Comment: @BroiSatse you should post this as an answer so the OP can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I said it as a comment, but will re-post it so the question might be marked as solved:

YAML is parsed using whitespaces, hence there should be no tabs in there (AFAIK it should also work with tabs only - no mixes though)

Comment: I discover the inconsistencies in my yml files by selecting the text in the Sublime Text editor, it shows .... or ..-- when is mixed.